# sub menu not positioning side by side

Tags: html, css

I found an issue with `.sub_menu` code `left:-;` and `transform:translateX(-%);`,So I changed position to relative and re-positioned with the two codes above, It seemed to work but now the two sub menus i have are no longer Side-By-Side. What they do is separate by a few centimeters top:, Not sure what made this happen, Any help would be appreciated,Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b92txask/1/) sub menu pops up when you hover over Gallery

```
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
  position:relative;
  top:-60%;
  left:-350%;
  transform:translateX(-40%);
  width: auto;
}

.sub_menu > li {
  display:inline-block;
}

.sub_menu li a {
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
}

.sub_menu li a:hover {
  background:#FF00FF;
  top:1em;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you. That code is a mess and very difficult to make a quick change to in order to achieve what you're asking for. Have you FireBug? You should inspect your elements and check their margin / padding etc. You're using things such as a negative % or over 100% on elements to try and counter the padding margin on their parents / siblings etc.

Comment: its not my fault why i do this, the site i use this on is a mess already.. i have to take certain things and position them around 1500px to the right and use ease-in-out when clicking on the menu bar and then they show visible with my target code, only way to do that.. there-for on some of the coding i have to put - to bring it left of the bar and no i dont use firebug

Comment: Browser based developer tools are one of the most powerful things available to you for debugging CSS and other browser issues. In Chrome and IE they are in built, press f12. FireBug for FireFox is a plug in and is my personal preference. Get to know all of them and master at least one of them and that will help you with issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you close to what you are looking for. I modified the css heavily. Change the `#right_menu` `line-height` and `right` position as well as the `.sub_menu` `top` position to change the height and position offsets of the menus.

EDITED: Moved all background colors to the `li` elements. Added `#right_menu li:hover {background-color:#ee00ee;}` to darken menu item on hover and updated the `.sub_menu li` gradient to match.

```css
body {
  font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica;
  background:url() no-repeat center 0,#000 url() left top;
  background-size:1670px 950px;
}

#right_menu {
    display: table;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 46px; /* Height of menu items */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 46px; /* Offset equal to line-height */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top 0;
    width: 100vh;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#right_menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}

#right_menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sub_menu /* same as #right_menu li ul */{
    display: none;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -46px; /* Offset equal to height (line-height) */
}

.sub_menu li {
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#77047e,#ee00ee);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(#77047e,#ee00ee);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(#77047e,#ee00ee);
    background:linear-gradient(#77047e,#ee00ee);
}

#right_menu li:hover {
    background: none; /* reset */
    background-color: #ee00ee;
}

#right_menu li:hover .sub_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="right_menu">
  <li><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile_about_me_friends">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile_interests_content">Interest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile_photo_galleries">Gallery</a>
     <ul class="sub_menu">
       <li><a href="#profile_password_photo_galleries">Password</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Password</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#profile_comments">Message Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just one question, now the hover doesn't work like before where when i hovered over all the buttons they would move a little top: as well as the sub menu..This allows the viewers to get an understanding on each button other than that awesome work, thanks

Comment: Just wanted to say ' Thanks Again.. "Awesome Job" no need to try and do that hover movement i can probably figure that out later on down the road, I'm sure you spent a while on this as it is..

Comment: I updated the answer to include hover effects that change the `background-color` on the `li` elements. I recommend this over changing the position or size of menu items as that can sometimes be a little disorientating to the user, especially as sub menus grow.

Comment: yes that's what i did instead of the movement, that's why i said no worries on the hover movement, thanks again